# Download XML via HTTPS

Tags: xml, powershell, https, copy

I'm trying to download XML file (Jenkins config.xml history file) from Jenkins HTTPS server. I searched here and elsewhere but still cannot find the way to get it working.

```
$url = "https://<server-path>/configOutput?type=xml&timestamp=2018-02-23_13-09-02"

$file = "d:\file.xml"
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Credentials = Get-Credential
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $file)
```

After supplying credentials to prompt I'm getting this error:

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The underlying connection
was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."
At D:\ps\jenkins-config\get_xml.ps1:7 char:1
+ $wc.DownloadFile($url,$file)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code (other than SSLv3 being broken), so the issue is probably with the network or the server. Check the Jenkins logs.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the problem is with log in. Jenkins expects logged in user and even though I supply correct credentials the information about successful login is not saved anywhere (session, cookie, ..) therefore I am still getting 403. So the problem here is to first log in (in PS script), save this info and then request the page from URL. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `Invoke-WebRequest` method:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ContentType 'application/xml' -OutFile $file -Credential $(Get-Credential) -Timeout 60
```

I've seen "configOutput" for job history care-of the JobConfigHistory plug-in. I've never seen it to get Jenkin's config file (the one in JENKINS_HOME). If you're trying to control a job's config, double check your URL.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this method too, got this for change:
`Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
At D:\ps\jenkins-config\test2.ps1:9 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ContentType 'application/xml' -OutFile $ ...

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`

Comment: Use a "-Verbose" to get more information. Can you access the URL using a browser (i.e., you're sure that URL is right?)?

Comment: Yep, I can access URL via browser, I need to logged in. So my issue now is how to log in, keep the session and access the desired URL.

Currently trying this:
`$url_xml = "https://<server-path>/configOutput?type=xml&timestamp=2018-02-23_13-09-02"
$url = "https://<server-path>"

$body = @{j_username='username';j_password='password'}
#j_username and j_password are on Jenkins login page

Invoke-WebRequest $url -SessionVariable 'Session' -Body $body -Method 'POST'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url_xml -WebSession $Session`

Comment: .. but what happens is blank IE window opens with `about:/ci/login?from=%2Fci%2F` in address bar .. (jenkins login URL is: https://<server-path>/ci/ .. and then another IE window pops up with second ($url_xml)

Comment: resulting in error:
`Invoke-WebRequest : Authentication required
At D:\ps\jenkins-config\test2.ps1:19 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest $url -SessionVariable 'Session' -Body $body -Method ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`

Comment: and:
`Invoke-WebRequest : Authentication required
At D:\ps\jenkins-config\test2.ps1:20 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url_xml -WebSession $Session
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`